# Unwanted blinking in animation

Tags: ios, animation

```
-(IBAction)duckAction:(id)sender{

    CABasicAnimation *moveDuck = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [moveDuck setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [moveDuck setDuration:.40];
    [moveDuck setRepeatCount:1];
    [moveDuck setAutoreverses:NO];
    [moveDuck setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                                 CGPointMake(btnDuck.center.x+25 ,btnDuck.center.y)]];
    [moveDuck setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                               CGPointMake(btnDuck.center.x -25, btnDuck.center.y)]];
    [btnDuck.layer addAnimation:moveDuck forKey:@"position"];

}

-(IBAction)frogAction:(id)sender{
    ptFrog = btnFrog.center;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00
                          delay:0.0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^ {
                         CGPoint position;
                         position.y = 577.0f;
                         position.x = 58.0f;
                         btnFrog.center = position;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         btnFrog.center = ptFrog;

                     }];
}
```

I have two buttons which are close to each other. First I press frog button then I press duck button at the end of frog animation there is a blink in frog button. I do not know why it is happening? How do I remove that blinking?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in Completion block dude.

```
 btnFrog.center = ptFrog;
```

after animation completed it immediately center it.That was the reason for blinking.  If you want to set the center then put the above code in animations block

Updates:

```
-(IBAction)frogAction:(id)sender{
    ptFrog = btnFrog.center;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00
                          delay:0.0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^ {
                         CGPoint position;
                         position.y = 577.0f;
                         position.x = 58.0f;
                         //btnFrog.center = position;

                         btnFrog.center = ptFrog;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
}
```

Comment: your code is a no-op, isn't it? Its `ptFrog = btnFrog.center; animate { btnFrog.center = ptFrog; }`

Comment: animation not working smoothly.is there any other way to solve this?